# perf_event_open() always get zero when specifying CPU ID

Tags: c++, linux, performance, x86, perf

I am reading Perf performance counters using this example:

https://gist.github.com/teqdruid/2473071

However, instead of:

```
fd[0] = perf_event_open(&attr[0], getpid(), -1, -1, 0);
```

I only want to know count events for the the caller thread (which is pinned to it's CPU earlier).

According to the man page I need to pass in the CPU ID:

```
pid > 0 and cpu >= 0
              This measures the specified process/thread only when
              running on the specified CPU.
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html

So I am passing the CPU id using `sched_getcpu()`:

```
fd[0] = perf_event_open(&attr[0], getpid(), sched_getcpu(), -1, 0);
```

However, I always get zero for any counter, whereas if I replace the cpu id with `-1` I do get results.

I check the CPU ID at the start is the same as the one when reading counters.

I am running using `sudo` etc.

Does `perf_event_open()` expect CPU ID in another way?

Comment: I don't see why you need to pass the CPU ID. Use `cpu=-1` to get it on any CPU. The pinning will keep it on the same CPU, so there's no need to limit the statistics.

Comment: @Barmar ah so if I use -1 and it's pinned, I will still only get the counter specific to that CPU? I thought the counter would be a global value for all CPUs?

Comment: Since it's pinned, it never runs on any other CPU. So all its counters are specific to that CPU.